# Access request body when isMaxSizeExceeded

Tags: java, playframework, multipartform-data, playframework-2.1

I'm using play 2.1.0 and want to implement file upload with several parameters, i.e. `multipart/form-data` form has some small fields and file itself.

If I upload the file without using annotation

`@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.MultipartFormData.class, maxLength = MAX_FILE_SIZE_B)`

and checking file size like `uploadedFile.length > MAX_SIZE` I can access request body and it's not null all the time.

If I'm using the annotation, when maxSizeExceeded `ctx.request().body().asMultipartFormData()` is null even my small parameters go first in the request sent by browser. Is it correct behaviour, is any way to get small parameters even file is too large?

Is it true that the first way is bad, because large files actually will be uploaded on the server?

Comment: The behavior is expected because, the payload is dropped once the payload size has exceeded the max_size limit. So, you can't access any form fields. Instead try to add those fields as a part of request headers, if that helps. Sorry for the late response, better late than never :).

Comment: @Sundar can you please create an answer and I'll accept it. Also link to the source will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is expected because, the header will contain the file size, and if the payload/file size has exceeded the max_size limit the server will not receive the file and the connection will be closed. So, you can't access any form fields. Instead try to add those fields as a part of request headers, if that helps.

There is no documentation that explains this, but that is how it is handled in http layer. The following [code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/j/JavaParsers.scala) might explain a bit, when the payload exceeds the limit it wraps the object with body = null.

To answer your question, yes the second approach is good and helps your server from accepting large files unnecessarily.